# How can I get the SVG line animation to work with multiple paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I researched these: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg

Working with Html5blank theme. My javascript code is:

```js
(function ($, root, undefined) {
 $(function () {
  'use strict';
  // DOM ready, take it away
   var paths = document.querySelectorAll('path.letter');
[].forEach.call(paths, function(path) {
  var length = path.getTotalLength();
  // Clear any previous transition
  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
    'none';
  // Set up the starting positions
  path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
  // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
  // picks up the starting position before animating
  path.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Define our transition
  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
    'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';
  // Go!
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
})                    
  });
    })(jQuery, this);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "svg line animation with multiple paths"?

Comment: Using the stroke-dasharray/stroke-dashoffset method to line draw a path except i am seeking to do it with multiple paths. The code i have written (with help from sources cited in links) works to a point each path now has a transition value, a stroke-dasharray path length and a stroke dash-offset of 0. But it doesn't animate. Hope that makes sense.